select data frame rows corresponding to max value in a specific column
set.seed(2024)
df <- data.frame(x1=rep(c(1:4),each=12), x2=rep(c("A","B","C"),each=4,times=4), y=runif(48), z=rep(c(12,4,19,8,58,2,33,32,25,70,5,25),each=4))

I'm trying to select rows for all unique letters that have the highest value in z.
In my example, A would be the rows:
37  4  A 0.0541251726 70
38  4  A 0.9661198864 70
39  4  A 0.0221378489 70
40  4  A 0.6473674888 70

for B:
17  2  B 0.1103110805 58
18  2  B 0.8632152062 58
19  2  B 0.1310691827 58
20  2  B 0.2954267922 58

For C, the largest z value is 25 when x1==3 and x1==4, so select the rows with the lowest value in x1:
33  3  C 0.1762014020 25
34  3  C 0.9733794478 25
35  3  C 0.6751627198 25
36  3  C 0.6809547509 25

Together, this is the expected result:
   x1 x2            y  z
37  4  A 0.0541251726 70
38  4  A 0.9661198864 70
39  4  A 0.0221378489 70
40  4  A 0.6473674888 70
17  2  B 0.1103110805 58
18  2  B 0.8632152062 58
19  2  B 0.1310691827 58
20  2  B 0.2954267922 58
33  3  C 0.1762014020 25
34  3  C 0.9733794478 25
35  3  C 0.6751627198 25
36  3  C 0.6809547509 25

This almost does the job:
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(x2) %>% slice(which.max(z))

but I need to select all other rows belonging to the same x1.

Almost there; one option using filter: df |> dplyr::filter(z == max(z), .by = x2) (optional |> dplyr::arrange(x2)).

It works great, many thanks @Friede. Would you like to post it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Per your comment, here an answer. Looks like you are explicitly after a {dplyr} solution. Hence, one option using filter():
df |> 
  dplyr::group_by(x2) |> 
  dplyr::filter(z == max(z)) |> 
  dplyr::filter(x1 == min(x1)) |> 
  dplyr::arrange(x2)

I will delete it if someone references a dupe. Pretty sure there must be at least one; couldn't find yet.

Thanks! Just noticed a little problem. Your code seems to select C when x1==3 and x1==4, because they have the same value of z (25). Is it possible to select the rows with the lowest x1 in case of ties?

You could subset two times in a by.
> do.call('rbind', by(df, df$x2, \(x) subset(x, z == max(z)) |> subset(x1 == min(x1))))
     x1 x2          y  z
A.37  4  A 0.05412517 70
A.38  4  A 0.96611989 70
A.39  4  A 0.02213785 70
A.40  4  A 0.64736749 70
B.17  2  B 0.11031108 58
B.18  2  B 0.86321521 58
B.19  2  B 0.13106918 58
B.20  2  B 0.29542679 58
C.33  3  C 0.17620140 25
C.34  3  C 0.97337945 25
C.35  3  C 0.67516272 25
C.36  3  C 0.68095475 25

